# Multiple folders for homestead not syncing

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vagrantfile, homestead

My first homestead project worked without a hitch here's the core part of the homstead.yaml

```
folders:
    - map: C:\dev\bitbucket
      to: /home/vagrant/bb

sites:
    - map: project.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/bb/example/project/public
```

now I wanted to add a different folder into the mix so I extended the yaml to

```
folders:
    - map: C:\dev\bitbucket
      to: /home/vagrant/bb
    - map: C:\dev\github
      to: /home/vagrant/gh

sites:
    - map: project.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/bb/example/project/public    
    - map: another.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/gh/example/another/public
```

I run `homestead provision` and now I can access another.dev but I got the error `No input file specified.` So I ran the command `homestead ssh` and  `cd /home/vagrant` followed by `ls` and all I see is the **bb** folder and not the **gh**
I found multiple places that mention multiple sites syntax, but couldn't find something mentioning multiple folders (although as the name suggests folders is plural, so I thought this should be possible)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

sometimes homestead doesn't provision correctly and needs a full reboot. while this isn't ideal, one workaround is to use `homestead halt` followed by `homestead up` to recreate the provisioning process for the VM.

Comment: In 2019 you have to use `vagrant halt` followed by `vagrant up`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a bit of my homestead file 
u are not allowed to change this directory /home/vagrant/Projects to something else

```
folders:
     - map: ~/Projects
       to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
   - map: aone.dev
     to: /home/vagrant/Projects/aone/public
   - map: booking.dev
     to: /home/vagrant/Projects/booking/public
   - map: nish.dev
     to: /home/vagrant/Projects/nish/public
   - map: shazdekocholo.dev
     to: /home/vagrant/Projects/shazdekocholo/public
   - map: hejab.dev
     to: /home/vagrant/Projects/hejab/public
```